# Error mientras intento recorrer cada fila de un dataframe usando Java Spark foreach

Tags: java, dataframe, foreach, scala, spark

**editado**

Estoy intentando iterar un dataframe fila por fila para coger valores y crear otro dataframe mas grande. En este ejemplo no uso datos del primero es solo para mostrar lo que estoy probando.

Siempre me da un error en el foreach que no entiendo

Ejemplo dataframe a iterar:

```
Dataset<Row> obtencionRents = spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
        new testRentabilidades("0000A0","PORTAL","4-ANUAL","asdasd","asdasd"),
        new testRentabilidades("00A00","PORTAL","","asdasd","sdasd"),
        new testRentabilidades("00A","PORTAL","4-ANUAL","asdasd","asdasd")
), testRentabilidades.class);
```

Función Foreach para recorrer el dataframe anterior:

```
obtencionRents.toJavaRDD().foreach(new VoidFunction<Row>() {
        public void call(Row r) throws Exception {

            //añadir registros a nueva lista/coleccion/etc

        }
    });
```

El error que me da:

```
Driver stacktrace:
2021-11-03 17:34:41 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 0 failed: foreach at CargarRentabilidades.java:154, took 0,812094 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:419)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:157)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades.transformacionRentabilidades(CargarRentabilidades.java:154)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades.coleccionRentabilidades(CargarRentabilidades.java:78)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades.coleccionCargaRentabilidades(CargarRentabilidades.java:52)
    at batchload.proceso.MainBatch.init(MainBatch.java:59)
    at batchload.BatchloadRentabilidades.main(BatchloadRentabilidades.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:419)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:157)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Versiones:

mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.0
Java 1.8
IntelliJ 2021 1.2 Community
Spark library versions 2.11

hadoop 2.7, spark 2.3.0, java driver 2.7, spark catalyst,core,hive,sql ....all 2.11:2.3.0, scala scala-library:2.11.12

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, Gracias!

Comment: no he conseguido que funcione el foreach, al final transforme el dataframe en una lista y la recorrí con for row:    List<Row> nueva lista = df.collectAsList();